# Sort an Array of Objects into ascending and descending order by string value JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, sorting, object

I have an Array of Objects. Each object contains String values and Number Values

```
const myArray = [
    {
        name: "Name 1",
        age: 25,
    },
    {
        name: "Name 2",
        age: 13,
    },    {
        name: "Name 3",
        age: 54,
    },    {
        name: "Name 4",
        age: 56,
    },    {
        name: "Name 5",
        age: 9,
    },
];
```

I want to allow the user to sort the Array by name. I have done this using the following code:

```
const compareByNameDescending = (a, b) => b.name.localeCompare(a.name);
const sortedArrayByNameDescending = people.sort(compareByNameDescending);
console.log(sortedArrayByNameDescending);
```

This correctly sorts the Array into Descending order.

I also want to allow the user to sort the Array by name in Ascending order. I have done this using the following code:

```
const compareByNameAscending = (a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
const sortedArrayByNameAscending = people.sort(compareByNameAscending);
console.log(sortedArrayByNameAscending);
```

```js
const people = [
    {
        name: "Name 1",
        age: 25,
    },
    {
        name: "Name 2",
        age: 13,
    },    {
        name: "Name 3",
        age: 54,
    },    {
        name: "Name 4",
        age: 56,
    },    {
        name: "Name 5",
        age: 9,
    },
];

const compareByNameDescending = (a, b) => b.name.localeCompare(a.name);
const sortedArrayByNameDescending = people.sort(compareByNameDescending);
console.log(sortedArrayByNameDescending);

const compareByNameAscending = (a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
const sortedArrayByNameAscending = people.sort(compareByNameAscending);
console.log(sortedArrayByNameAscending);
```

However, this produces the same output as the above code. Why is this and how could I cause the program to correctly display the Array in Ascending order?

I have looked at multiple different articles, videos and questions on Stack Overflow and have not been able to find a working solution.

Comment: Your code appears to work fine. (I fixed the array name problem, "people" instead of "myArray".)

Comment: In the browser, the code does not work like this

Comment: Is it not the same code? If not, how is it different. Both of your `.sort()` callbacks do exactly what you want them to do. One note: the `.sort()` call rearranges the original array; it does not make a new array.

Answer (score 1):

```
const myArray = [
    { name: "Name 1", age: 25 },
    { name: "Name 2", age: 13 },
    { name: "Name 3", age: 54 },
    { name: "Name 4", age: 56 },
    { name: "Name 5", age: 9 },
];

function sortArrayByName(sortDirection) {
  // Create a shallow copy of the original array
  const sortedArray = myArray.slice();

  // Sorting in ascending order by 'name'
  if (sortDirection === 'asc') {
    sortedArray.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name));
  }
  // Sorting in descending order by 'name'
  else if (sortDirection === 'desc') {
    sortedArray.sort((a, b) => b.name.localeCompare(a.name));
  }
  // If the sortDirection is neither 'asc' nor 'desc', do nothing (retain original order)

  return sortedArray;
}

// Example usage:
const sortedAscending = sortArrayByName('asc');
console.log(sortedAscending);

const sortedDescending = sortArrayByName('desc');
console.log(sortedDescending);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).